# Image upload to Facebook from HTML drag and drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, html

I've got a PHP script that can upload images stored on my server to a Facebook post. I've tried and tested it and the post gets to Facebook just fine.

I also have a drag and drop area on my webpage, based on [this tutorial](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/javascript/drag-files-into-the-browser-from-the-desktop-HTML5.html#fbid=206HrHUIQjE). What I've hit a brick wall on is getting the file dropped onto the DOM element that I'm listening to and then passing it over to the PHP script or, for that matter, a Javascript function.

I suspect that Javascript might be my best option, so I've looked at Dropzone.js but it appears to require that the image first goes to my server and then onto Facebook - I'd really like to avoid that for storage and upload time reasons.

I think in terms of a Javascript solution it's got something to do with `FileReader()` and here's my code so far:

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault();
    var files = evt.dataTransfer.files;
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
    if (!f.type.match('image.*')) { continue; }
    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = (function(theFile) {
        return function(e) {
            var blob = e.target.result;
            var fd = new FormData();
            fd.append("access_token",fbAccessToken);
            fd.append("source", blob);fd.append("message","This is another post test...");
    try{
        $.ajax({
            url:"https://graph.facebook.com/" + fbuserid + "/photos?access_token=" + fbAccessToken,
            type:"POST",
            data:fd,
            processData:false,
            contentType:false,
            cache:false,
            console.log("success " + data);
        },
        error:function(shr,status,data){
                console.log("error " + data + " Status " + shr.status);
        },
        complete:function(){
                    console.log("Ajax Complete");
        }
    });
    }catch(e){console.log(e);}
};})(f);

fileReader.readAsDataURL(f);
}
}
```

and I can see that raw image data is accessible through there but then how can I pass that to the `Formdata`?

Comment: Not sure I've got it but what browser do you use?-
Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

Comment: I'm using Safari 7 and Firefox 27